# How to solve the 500 Server error in asp.net mvc without enable the error show stuff

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc 4 for my project. my project is going well. I wonder about a thing.

I make a controller Test and ActionResult Index() this action doesn't need any viewdata or any kind of things.

Now When I test it in my local computer it's should work and it is. no problem.

Now amazing thing is it's doesn't work on server.

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

I am amazed that what happen to my code when everything work without any exception.

Now when I told other people about log they don't have anything. I don't want to install any nuget package on live site to test it. Do someone help me to solve this without adding any error checking module.

How I can check the issue on server.

Comment: "I am amazed that what happen to my code when everything work without any exception." - I'm not! It's quite common.  Permissions, relative paths, not deploying all components, etc

Comment: Which hosting provider are you using? many of them will allow you to enable iis debugging in the control panel so that you will get the regular asp.net error page with the stack trace.

Comment: This is my own server. the person who maintain hosting is out so I thing to solved this without showing the error on site.

Answer (score 1):

IIS will log 500 errors in the [Event Logs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-event-viewer). So assuming you have access to the server, you can check there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm sorry but you have to be willing to do something... If you don't want to install packages like `Elmah` or enable remote `iis debugging` or etc... the only other thing that comes to my mind is for you to just start changing random stuff and hope it works. Also, most of these 500 internal server errors are caused by something in the `web.config` file. Make sure everything is set and good in there.

Answer (score 1):

A very  common reason for getting 500 Internal Server error is : Issue in Web.Config file.
Many times one can have some tags not closed properly OR missing Double quotes etc..

In general some syntax error is present most of the times in Web.Config. So make sure atleast you PASS this case.